# hide active div on clicking out side the div

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#our_location').click(function(){

    $('#locations').show();

    });

$('#locations a').click(function(){
    $('#f_w').hide();


    var id = $(this).attr('id');

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "map_response.php",
       data: ({id: id}),
       success: function(response){
        //alert(response);
        $('#map_n_vilage').html(response);
        $('#map_n_vilage').show();
        $('.villages').show();
       }
   });


    });

});
```

When I click on a link `#our_location` a div `#locations` opens. When I click any anchor tag in `#locations` ajax is called and `#map_n_vilage` div is shown... Now all I want is that if I click on any other thing than these divs, all my these div's should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function to hide the divs:

```
function hideDivs() {
   $('.villages').hide();
   $('#map_n_vilage').hide();
   $('#locations').hide();
}
```

You could attach this to a new handler for any div that is clicked and only execute `hideDivs` is the name does not equal `villages`, `map_n_village`, `locations`.  You can also check if they are visible by using the `:visible` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Normally due to event bubbling, whenever any thing on the html page is clicked, the body also gets a click event. So something like this:

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != "your-main-div-id") {
    //hide whatever div you want to hide
   }
 });
```

Where main-div-id should be some control's id which if gets clicked, you don't want to hide your div.
You can even remove that part but I think you will need that in your case.